# matching a word from the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to match words strating with # from a textarea

```
 var start=/#/ig; // # Match
 var word=/#(\w+)/ig; //#abc Match
 var content=$('#text').val();
 var go= content.match(start); //Content Matching #
 var name= content.match(word); //Content Matching #abc
```

Here it checks the value in the text area and gives the output word which starts with #
If there is two matches found it's showing the two matches,but i need only the last match

Comment: Does removing the `g` flag help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.match()` function returns an array of matches.

If you want to select the last element, you need to select it like this:

```
name[name.length-1];
```

- `name.length` returns the number of elements
- `-1` because array keys start with 0 and not 1

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5kdM/), thanks to [Dave Briand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2638964/dave-briand)

Comment: here how can i check whether the current word i am typing in the textbox contains # or not

Comment: If it is in the matching array, then it contains a #. If you want to check if the array is empty, check if it is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
content = "~test content ~thanks ok ~fine";    
strFine = content.lastIndexOf('~');
```

It gives index for last match character or word or string what you have passed...

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
 var text = $('textarea').val();   // "#maxi kcdjnd dcjjncd #ijicd" 

 //Find all ocurrences of words starting with # and ending in space, period or end of text
 var lastMatch = text.match(/(#.*?)(\s|$|\.)/g).pop();

 // match returns ["maxi", "#ijicd"]. pop will get the last element
```

Answer (score 0):

The re method `match` usually returns an array. To get the last match, you can use the following:

```
var name= content.match(word);
var lastMatch = (!!name) ? name.pop() : name;
```

If there's no match, the method returns `null` and you want to be sure you do not try to manipulate `null` as an array.